# Starting HornetQ in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jndi, hornetq

I am trying to start hornetQ 2.0.0.GA in Tomcat.

My application, when initializing, will try to start hornetq server in this way:

org.jnp.server.Main jndiServer;

jndiServer = new Main();

jndiServer.setNamingInfo(naming);

jndiServer.setPort(1099);

jndiServer.setBindAddress("localhost");

jndiServer.setRmiPort(1098);

jndiServer.setRmiBindAddress("localhost");

jndiServer.start();

...

jmsServer = new JMSServerManagerImpl(hornetqServer, jmsConfig);

jmsServer.start();

I need the jndi service started, so that then I can lookup for a ConnectionFactory to integrate it with Bitronix TM.

It runs ok in an standalone test, but when I run it in tomcat,

I get an error in jndiServer.start();

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:175)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:293)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:256)
    at org.jnp.server.Main.initJnpInvoker(Main.java:462)
    at org.jnp.server.Main.start(Main.java:422)
    ... 50 more

Any help?

Thanks,

Demian

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713281/hornetq-on-tomcat

Comment: btw 2.0.0.GA is too old, you should use 2.2.5+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's a method setJNDIContext at the JMSServerManager on HQ 2.0 (since you are instantiating your own context).

On 2.2.5, there's an intermediate interface called BindingRegistry. You can use that to plug your naming context to whatever you want on Tomcat (including JNDI)

Comment: Thanks Clebers, I have seen the link you posted, but not one of the links there. This one helped me to make it work:

http://wash-inside-out.blogspot.com/2010/08/hornetq-jms-integration-with-tomcat.html

Comment: Try getting a newer version than 2.0.0. A lot of fixes since then.